# How to read project.properties and all paths of library project from it with Ant?

Tags: android, ant

I tried to read project.properties with following content. I've used property with prefix, but can not reach my point.

```
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=submodules/Switchbar
android.library.reference.2=submodules/Volley
android.library.reference.3=libs/ActionBar/library
```

I just wanna get string or list[submodules/Switchbar,submodules/Switchbar,libs/ActionBar/library], and try to use them for other requirements.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a sinle property like

```
android.library.reference=submodules/Switchbar,submodules/Volley,libs/ActionBar/library
```

and use it in your build.xml.

For example, you can use `<for>` or `<foreach>` to iterate through the list and execute codes on each item. You may be able to use it directly in some tasks as they support such kind of "comma-seperated list" natively (e.g. `include` and `exclude` of `<zip>`).

If you want to keep the current way (write multiple properties with same prefix), you can use `<script>` to write scripts in your ant build file to deal with the properties. You can use ruby, python, Beanshell (Java), groovy and so on. You can also use this way to handle the single property.

So, it's better for you to post more on your question: what is your "other requirements"? How will you use the properties or "list"?

Answer (score 0):

Android's ant build-file has a predefined task for this:

```
<getlibpath projectPath="${any.path.to.android.project}" libraryFolderPathOut="full.project.library.path.list" />
```

It returns all the library projects involved in specific build (including lib projects of lib projects).

It is available after

```
<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml"/>
```

which is included automatically in initial build script (after you run `android update project -p <path-to-android-project>`)

More precisely, the next part of "${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml makes the magic (I'm including getlibpath  this wa directly in my build-scripty)

```
    <!-- jar file from where the tasks are loaded -->
    <path id="android.antlibs">
        <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/ant-tasks.jar" />
    </path>

    <!-- Custom tasks -->
    <taskdef resource="anttasks.properties" classpathref="android.antlibs" />
```